# How to avoid relaunching task while it's status is still running on Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have deployed a Spring Batch project as a task on Spring Cloud Data Flow.

I have launched the task for the first time (It was going to run about 5 minutes which made the status of task is "running"). However, I have relaunched this task for the second time when it's status is running and it worked again.

1) How can I configure that the task could not be relaunched until it's completed status for the last time.
2) Besides, I found that when stopping the job, it will execute until it finishes the current step(My job has 2 steps and the second step was not executed ). However, are there any ways to shut down it (step 1) immediately when I stop the job?

Comment: For better help sooner, edit to add a [mre] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to avoid relaunching task while it's status is still running on Spring Cloud Data Flow

Spring Cloud Task 2.0.0 added a feature that allows you to prevent tasks from running concurrently. See https://spring.io/blog/2018/05/07/spring-cloud-task-2-0-0-release-is-now-available#restricting-concurrent-task-execution

You need to activate the `spring.cloud.task.singleInstanceEnabled=true` property.

You can find more details in the [Restricting Spring Cloud Task Instances](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_restricting_spring_cloud_task_instances) section.

Comment: thanks you @Mahmoud Ben Hassine. However, where should I place that property? in application.properties of Spring Cloud DataFlow or in application.properties of Spring Batch project

Comment: spring.cloud.task.singleInstanceEnabled=true has locked my task permanently(I can not run it again after the 1st run). How to set up that task can be launched again while it's previous launch has been finished?

Comment: Is your task a spring batch job? If yes, then its normal because a spring batch job instance cannot be re-executed if it completes successfully. You need to change the parameters to run a new job instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JobExplorer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/explore/JobExplorer.html) class for checking running jobs, see `jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(jobName)` method.

In your JobLauncher class you can something like that:

```
@Component
public class MyJobLauncher {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyJobLauncher.class);

    private final Job job;

    private final JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    private final JobExplorer jobExplorer;

    @Autowired
    public MyJobLauncher(@Qualifier("myJob") Job job, JobLauncher jobLauncher, JobExplorer jobExplorer) {
        this.job = job;
        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
        this.jobExplorer = jobExplorer;
    }

    public void launchJob() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException,
            JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, IOException {

        if (jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions("myJob").isEmpty()) {
            LOG.info("Starting myJob");
            jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
            LOG.info("Stopping myJob");
        }
    }
}
```

For shutting down the job, check [JobExecution.stop()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecution.html#stop--) method which can be fetched from `jobExplorer.getJobExecution()` method.

Comment: Thanks for your helps. However, your solution may not meet my problem. I will try it